# How to install ng-table from npm?

Tags: angularjs, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install [ng-table package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-table) from npm using:

```
npm install ng-table --save
```

I get this error log:

```
npm WARN package.json moodle-angular-pooc@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json moodle-angular-pooc@0.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'types/angular' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'ng-table'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "ng-table" "--save"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/shared/moodle/report/angularjspooc
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vagrant/shared/moodle/report/angularjspooc/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

This sounds like a 404 error, but I don't understand why since there is a npm package and a github repo.

How to proceed to install `ng-table` with `npm` ?

Comment: Did you try `npm install angular@1.5.7 --save` first?

Comment: angular was well installed before. I tried with your version, same problem.

Comment: try also this one npm install ng-table@next --save

Comment: i just tried: same problem.

Comment: Having same issue with angular-ui-router-title:0.1.1.  Has worked previously...